# Acceder desde C# al enlace de un HyperLinkField de un GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Tengo el siguiente GridView en ASP.NET:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1">
        <Columns>
            <asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="ID" DataTextField="ID" DataNavigateUrlFields="ID" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="_Ficha/?ficha={0}" SortExpression="ID" />
        </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Me gustaría acceder en C# al texto de cada enlace de la columna del GridView, pero siempre me da error.

Lo he intentado de esta forma y no funciona:

```
GridView1.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[0].Text
```

También lo he intentado de esta otra forma y tampoco:

```
( (HyperLink) GridView1.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[0].Controls[0] ).Text
```

Os adjunto una imagen de mi GridView:

[image: GridView]

Lo que necesito es poder acceder al texto de esos enlaces (por ejempo, 1582, o 1583...) que aparecen en la columna "ID" para guardarlos en variables. No consigo hacerlo y necesito ayuda. Gracias! :(

Comment: en que evento esperas capturar ese valor?

Comment: Hola, Byron. Mi idea es añadir otra columna con botones (uno por fila), tal que si hago clic, por ejemplo, en el botón de la fila del ID 1585, se me active otro GridView con toda la información del registro de ID = 1585. No sé si me explico. Necesito meter los ID's en variables, como si fueran texto (o enteros, no me importa), pero al ser enlaces y no texto corriente me da problemas.

Comment: En resumen, que necesito acceder a su valor para un evento de tipo "OnRowCommand". Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Agrega el evento `OnSelectedIndexChanged` en tu GridView para obtener el valor deseado

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged "> ...
```

tu GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged quedaría así , con la variable `e` de tipo `EventArgs`  **esta es la clase base para las clases que contienen datos de eventos**

```
void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 String valor = ( (HyperLink) GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Controls[0] ).Text
     //....
}
```

Si desea realizar esta operación para el Evento `onrowcommand` también deberá añadir a su grid dicho evento `onrowcommand=Gridview1_RowCommand"`

y para obtener el index de la fila sería

```
int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
```

`String valor = ( (HyperLink) GridView1.Rows[index].Cells[0].Controls[0] ).Text`

Comment: Hola, Joel. ¿Sabrías cómo sería para un evento de tipo "OnRowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)"? Un saludo.

Comment: @spm.1989 Actulizé mi respuesta , resolvió su problema ?

Answer (score 1):

@spm

Para obtener el valor del ID, no es necesario que recorras o intentes buscar el control HiperLink.

---

Aprovecha los [DataKeyNames](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeynames(v=vs.110).aspx) que le asignaste, en este caso ID. Donde `RowIndex` es el valor del indice de donde quieres obtenerlo.

```
var Id = GridView1.DataKeys[RowIndex].Values["ID"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes agregar una nueva columna que permita seleccionar la fila, para este ejemplo al hacer clic en linkBoton "Seleccionar" se dispara el evento "RowCommand" del control GridView.
[image: GridView con un botón seleccionar]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al hacer clic por ejemplo en linkBoton "Seleccionar" en la fila 6 del gridview por ejemplo, se dispara el evento "RowCommand":

(Para agregar el evento, solo se debe seleccionar el control gridView, mostrar las propiedades y dar doble clic en el evento "RowCommand" El código se genera automáticamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es un código de ejemplo que probablemente le ayude a construir el suyo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Básicamente toma los argumentos del propio GridView para recuperar con el clic al botón la acción realizada (selección de fila) y el numero de la fila.

Answer (score -1):

Intenta obtenerlo en un evento del `HyperLinkField`:

```
if(sender is Control)
{
    HyperLinkField controlLink= sender as Control;
    string texto= controlLink.Text;
}
```

O si no es en el evento del link, puedes intentar con:

```
( (HyperLink) teamGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Controls[0] ).Text
```